# ssh-copy-id ubuntu: permission denied after deleting .ssh

Tags: 12.04, ssh

Few weeks ago I generated my SSH keys, registered my public key to the server etc etc. Everything went perfect.

Now I wanted to generate an other couple of SSH keys on another machine (on ubuntu) and do the same things: same user, different keys. The first time I tried everything went, more or less, right, but later, I had some issues, so I had the genius idea of deleting the .ssh folder and all the relative keys inside and restarting everything from scratch. The result is that now I am not even able to register the new keys on the server and I do not know what to try anymore!

```
$ ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub username@server.example.com
```

asks me for my passphrase, which doesn't recognize, terminating with something like

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)
```

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, once you register to a website with a public key, you need to use the *same* keys if you want the *same* identity on a different computer. When you create a new ssh key with the same user id, its different from the one you created previously, because it uses random data to create a key pair.

If you have .ssh folder from the first computer which you created the keys and registered it, simply copy it to the second machine and it should work fine. Once you have that folder, you can give the same password and you should be authenticated.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to do it! I know that the 2 keys are different, but when I first created on the second machine the keys, I could register the public one on the server. Everything got messed up after I deleting the .ssh folder on the second machine... This is why I couldn't make sense of it

Comment: In that case, if you cant recover the ssh folder, you need to create yet another key pair and add it to the website. Photorec is supposedly good at recovery.

Comment: Yes, I have done it, but it doesn't accept my passphrase (the new one, relative to the new keys). So, i can't add it to the server.

Comment: If you recovered your original .ssh which contains the very first credentials which you added to website, it must work, else, you are typing a wrong password. BTW, with github like websites, you need to add your new keys through the web interface, right? Is it similar to that in your case?